# Ajax file upload not working in IE7

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer-7, asyncfileupload

I've used this plugin for file upload via Ajax in asp.net mvc3.
http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxSubmit
But it won't work in IE7.

```
$("#Controls").submit(function () {
            var options = {
                url: "/Education/upDoc",
                datatype: "json",
                success: showResponse
            };
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
});

function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
        alert("sr");
        alert("Sr  " + responseText.success);
        if (responseText.success == true) {
            //some code
        }
    }

<form action='' id='Controls' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<table>
                        <tr> 
                        <td>File Type</td> 
                        <td><span class='leftten'></span></td> 
                        <td> 
                        @*<select id='documentType' name='documentType'> 

                        </select> *@
                        @Html.DropDownList("documentType", doctypelist, new { @id = "documentType" })
                        </td> 

                        <td><img src='../../img/AlertSign.jpg'  class='errImgDoc' data-style-tooltip='tooltip-shiny-red' title='' id='errFileType'  height='18px' width='20px'/></td> 
                        <td><span class='leftfortytwo'></span></td> 
                        <td><input type='file' id='file' name='file' /></td> 
                        <td><img src='../../img/AlertSign.jpg'  class='errImgDoc' data-style-tooltip='tooltip-shiny-red' title='' id='errFile'  height='18px' width='20px' /></td> 
                        <td><span class='leftfortytwo'></span></td> 
                        <td>Name</td> 
                        <td><span class='leftten'></span></td> 
                        <td><input type='text' id='description' name='description' /></td> 
                        </tr> 
                        </table> 
                        <br /> 
                        <div align='right'> 
                        <table><tr> 
                        <td><input type='button' id='eduUploadCancel' class='Cancel' onmouseover='CancelHover(this)' onmouseout='CancelMouseOut(this)' onclick='Cancel(this)' /></td><td><span class='leftten'></span></td><td><input type='submit' id='eduUploadSave' class='Save' onmouseover='SaveHover(this)' onmouseout='SaveMouseOut(this)' /></td></tr></table> 
                        </div>

</form>
```

Here,`showResponse()` is never called with IE7. Works fine on Chrome and Firefox.Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IE 7 is old browser and not support XMLHttpRequest Level 2.

> For older browsers, a fallback technology is used which involves
>   iframes since it is not possible to upload files using the level 1
>   implmenentation of the XMLHttpRequest object. This is a common
>   fallback technique, but it has inherent limitations. The iframe
>   element is used as the target of the form's submit operation which
>   means that the server response is written to the iframe. This is fine
>   if the response type is HTML or XML, **but doesn't work as well if the
>   response type is script or JSON,** both of which often contain
>   characters that need to be repesented using entity references when
>   found in HTML markup.

http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload

Comment: So if my response was plain text or xml, it would work in IE?

Comment: Yes I think, but it should be better if you test it.

Comment: Maybe try returning plain text JSON and then use JSON.parse()